# Plot paraboloid surface fitting

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, curve-fitting

How can I plot the paraboloid after fitting it using Python? in order to get that [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kMug.png)

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

doex = [0.4,0.165,0.165,0.585,0.585]
doey = [.45, .22, .63, .22, .63]
doez = np.array([1, .99, .98,.97,.96])

def paraBolEqn(data,a,b,c,d):
    x,y = data
    return -(((x-b)/a)**2+((y-d)/c)**2)+1.0


popt,pcov=opt.curve_fit(paraBolEqn,np.vstack((doex,doey)),doez,p0=[1.5,0.4,1.5,0.4])
print(popt)
```

Comment: I have a previous stackoverflow answer that might be useful, I think it has the code you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988797/how-to-do-two-dimensional-regression-analysis-in-python/46989269#46989269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need to know is documented at the [mplot3d tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), where the different methods to make 3d plots in matplotlib are presented.

Your desired plot can be reproduced using the methods `Axes3D.plot_wireframe` and `Axes3D.scatter`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(np.min(doex), np.max(doex),10), np.linspace(np.min(doey),np.max(doey), 10))
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, paraBolEqn((x,y), *popt))
ax.scatter(doex, doey, doez, color='b')
```

which results in the following plot:

[image]