# fitting function for 3d surface from x,y,z points

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

How do I fit this data [(link to data)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r3p73k0qk9byer/data.csv?dl=0) to a function? I need a funzion has z=f(x,y). I have tryed to plot the data in 3-d scatter plot and I get this.[image]

So far I have tried to build the surface with this code but I find some holes in the surface.

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata 
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):200j,min(y):max(y):200j]
grid_z=griddata([x,y],z,(grid_x,grid_y),method='linear')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(grid_x,grid_y, grid_z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

[image]

Has you can see tyhe srufce is not closed on the top edge.

I need to kown affter having calculated f(x,y) if the obtained z point is in the surface.
How can I achive it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988797/how-to-do-two-dimensional-regression-analysis-in-python/46989269#46989269 has some plotting code you might use for contour, surface and scatter plots. It also fits some 3D data similarly to what you are asking about.

Comment: your data is bending back, so depending on which axis is dependent/ independent there is no function, i.e. z = f( x, y ) is not unique. So no surprise that this does not work. You could try to transform the data or check, e.g. x = g( y, z )

Comment: or you try a parameter surface `( x, y, z ) = parameter_function( s, t )`